# Variable Scope Issue in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to catch the `change()` event in jQuery for two `select` elements. I'm trying to do it in a loop so I don't have to cut and paste the same code.

This line is having issues though `var x = $("#"+fields[i]).val();`

```
fields = ['foo', 'bar'];

for (var i=0; i < fields.length; i++)
{
    $("#"+fields[i]).change(function () {
            var x = $("#"+fields[i]).val();
            alert(x);
    });
}

<form>
    <select id="foo">
        <option value="first">first</option>
        <option value="second">second</option>
    </select>
    <select id="bar">
        <option value="third">third</option>
        <option value="fourth">fourth</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mLc5p/6/

**EDIT**

Sorry, that was an overly simplified example. I actually want to get a bunch of nearby fields without having to do a bunch of cut and paste. Here is my actual code:

```
var fieldnames = ['start_date', 'end_date']
for (var i=0; i < fieldnames.length; i++)
{
    var fieldname = fieldnames[i];

$("#event_"+fieldname+"_date, #event_"+fieldname+"_hour, #event_"+fieldname+"_minute, #event_"+fieldname+"_ampm").change(function(){

    var d = $("#event_"+fieldname+"_date").val();
    var h = $("#event_"+fieldname+"_hour").val();
    var m = $("#event_"+fieldname+"_minute").val();
    var ampm = $("#event_"+fieldname+"_ampm").val();

    $("#event_"+fieldname).val(d + ' ' + h + ':' + m + ampm);

    if ( $("#event_"+fieldname).val() == " :" ){
        $("#event_"+fieldname).val("");
    }

    if (fieldname == "start_date")
    {
        $.validator.methods.validMoment.call(this, $("#event_"+fieldname).val(), $("#event_"+fieldname), null);
    }else
    {
        $.validator.methods.validOptionalMoment.call(this, $("#event_"+fieldname).val(), $("#event_"+fieldname), null);
    }
});
```

}

I guess I could just generate the code in Ruby instead of having to worry about doing any tricks in Javascript, but I'm curious...

Comment: Use: `var x = this.value;` http://jsfiddle.net/mLc5p/8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `$.each` for your iteration.

```
var fields = ['foo', 'bar'];

$.each(fields, function(idx, field){
     $("#"+field).change(function () {
            var x = $("#"+field).val();
            alert(x);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mLc5p/12/

this will fix the scope issue. The problem is that `i` will be 2 after your normal for loop iteartion and `i` won't be saved in a scope for every iteration. At the end at execution time of your handler `i` will always be 2. `$.each` keeps the scope for every iteation seperate automaticly.

And for the sake of completeness the non-jQuery solution for this issue is:

```
var fields = ['foo', 'bar'];

for (var i=0; i < fields.length; i++){
    (function(i){
       $("#"+fields[i]).change(function () {
            var x = $("#"+fields[i]).val();
            alert(x);
        });
    })(i);
}
```

which has basicly the same effect as the above solution. Your code is wrapped inside a function and i is "glued" to your function scope as an argument to the self executing function.

Comment: I think this is what I want actually. I've updated my example with actual code since my example was too simple.

Answer (score 2):

you should change it into

```
$("#"+fields[i]).change(function () {
        var x = this.value;
        alert(x);
});
```

with your code, the problem is that whatever field you change you will always show the value of last field (due to the `for` cycle). In other words: when the `change` event occurs the value of `fields[i]` in the `alert` statement shows always <del>the value of the last field</del> undefined (as Chris correctly remind me).

as a sidenote there's no need to use jQuery: you may use `this.value`

Comment: Its not even the last element. Its undefined since `i` is 2 after the iteration due to the `i++` in the for loop and fields[2] is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Nooooo... No Loops. Just create a single event handler and use the `this` keyword to get the correct element.

```
$("select").change(function(){
    var x = $(this).val();
    alert(x);
});
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/jUSvE/)

Comment: This was an overly simplified example. I actually have a number of values I want to read that nearby. It just seems like a lot of cutting and pasting

Comment: @Dex: So show the real example, I am sure there will be a better way

Answer (score 0):

You should tru `this` like

```
var fields = ['foo', 'bar'];
for (var i=0; i < fields.length; i++)
{
    $("#"+fields[i]).change(function () {
        var x = $(this).val();// use this in place of fields[i]
        alert(x);
    });
}
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mLc5p/7/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this pointer in the for loop. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sid2varun/mLc5p/11/)

```
var fields = ['foo', 'bar'];

for (var i=0; i < fields.length; i++)
{
    $("#"+fields[i]).change(function () {
            var x = $(this).val();
            alert(x);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try following:

```
fields = ['foo', 'bar'];

for (var i=0; i < fields.length; i++)
{
    $("#"+fields[i]).change(function () {
        var x = $(this).val();
        alert(x);
    });
}
```

working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mLc5p/10/

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
var x = $("#"+fields[i]).val();
```

To:

```
var x = $(this).val();
```